# Merging two tuple of tuples

Tags: python, list, merge, tuples

I have two tuples `a = (('1',), ('2',))`
and `b = (('3',), ('4',))`

I need an output like

```
result = (('1','3',), ('2','4',))
```

I have tried converting the tuples into a list and used `zip` to merge into a single tuple `tuple(zip(list(a), list(b)))` and also `tuple(zip(a,b))` which yields `((('1',), ('3',)), (('2',), ('4',)))` as the result.

What should I be doing to get the desired result? I saw about immutability of tuples but I am getting the tuples from another service and I all I can do is to convert the obtained tuple to a list to get the expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zipping is the right approach, but you then have to flatten your paired tuples still; you could concatenate them:

```
result = tuple(x + y for x, y in zip(a, b))
```

Alternatively, flatten your `a` and `b` tuples *before* zipping:

```
result = tuple(zip((v for t in a for v in t), (v for t in b for v in t)))
```

Flattening can also be done with [`itertools.chain()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain), which is perhaps more readable:

```
from itertools import chain

result = tuple(zip(chain(*a), chain(*b)))
```

Demo:

```
>>> a = (('1',), ('2',))
>>> b = (('3',), ('4',))
>>> tuple(x + y for x, y in zip(a, b))
(('1', '3'), ('2', '4'))
>>> tuple(zip((v for t in a for v in t), (v for t in b for v in t)))
(('1', '3'), ('2', '4'))
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> tuple(zip(chain(*a), chain(*b)))
(('1', '3'), ('2', '4'))
```

Comment: The only problem I encounter here is that the tuples are not of same size. For instance when `b = (('3',), ('4',), ('5',))`, the result doesn't have the `('','5')`. How to make this work when they are of different size?

Comment: @NagarajanShanmuganathan: use [`itertools.zip_longest()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) and provide a `fillvalue` argument. For the flatten-first case that'd be `''`, the flatten-after case you'd use `('',)`.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this maybe?

```
[i + x for i, x in zip(a, b)]
```